# RewriteRule to rewrite /folder/subfolder/file to /?f=folder/subfolder/file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Pretty straightforward - just wondering how do I rewrite this:

`/folder/subfolder/file`

`/?f=folder/subfolder/file`

And the number of folders/subfolders might vary, so what I really want is anything after the / in that path (that does not already have ?f= in it) redirected to the path with ?f= added in front of it.

If I add this

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?f=$1 [L]`

it works just fine but doesn't recognize the existence of ?f= in the URL already, and breaks that existing link with ?f= in there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)f= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?f=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which does not do the rewriting if the `f` querystring is already there.
With [QSA] you keep the other possible querystring values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.[^\?]*)$ /?f=$1 [L]
```